# Why isn't the toilet water refilling from under the rim?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

So last night, my toilet clogged for the first time in the two years we've had it, and it clogged badly though I don't know why (without being too TMI, it was a normal #2).  Hours of plunging didn't help, so I scooped out water and did a baking soda/vinegar/very hot water treatment and left it overnight.  In the morning, I used an auger and it easily unclogged.

Now, it flushes, but when it refills, it slowly rises from the bottom and no water comes out from the little holes under the rim.

What might be wrong and how can I fix it?  Thank you!!

P.S.- We do not have kids so I am certain no foreign objects went in the toilet.

Answer (score 1):

The water that comes from under the rim, but after the flush comes from a flexible tube that goes from the flush valve (typically on the left of the tank) to the top of the pipe in the center of the tank.  As the water refills the tank, the tube sprays water down the pipe which leads down to the rim and bowl.

This fill tube can come off or get kinked.

Comment: Thank you.  I looked and all seems hooked up as described, but no water comes out of the tube as the the tank refills.  It seems to be attached everywhere.  Is there anything I should be looking at, to fix it?  I took a video but I'm not sure how to upload it here.

Comment: I just watched it again closely, and I believe the tube is trying to spray, but it only sprays a little air and a few droplets.  Does that mean there is something going on with the fill valve?  If so, any thoughts as to how to try to rectify the situation?

Comment: The rim clean/bowl fill water comes from the fill valve (aka ballcock valve). If there is inadequate flow you should first check for any kinks in the rim filler tube to the overflow pipe which it spays into (make sure the tank lid is not pinching it too). Then, shut off the water supply and open the fill valve to inspect for debris, crack open the supply valve to flush the fill valve. Replace fill valve diaphragms/washers as necessary or replace the fill valve.

Comment: I agree with @JimmyFix-it except just go all the way and replace the fill valve. They are not costly at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My problem ended up being that the new spongy gasket I had installed, which connected the toilet tank to the base, was now blocking the inlet holes. You wouldn’t notice this just looking directly down into the toilet when installing.